# How to extract a file from hiberfil.sys?

Tags: sleep, hibernate, file-recovery

I put my computer in sleep mode yesterday, and when I turned it back on, a file had been rolled back to the state it was in when I initially turned the computer on for the first time that day. After some googling, I found that the file may still be accessible in `hiberfil.sys`, although it was not in hibernation mode specifically.

How can I get that file back, if that is even remotely possible? Am I looking at the wrong file? Is there a similar file for sleep mode?

Answer (score 1):

You may try looking at hiberfil.sys using the search function of a hex editor.  This will probably only be a sane thing to do if it's a text file, and even then, there's no guarantee that the memory pages containing your file would be contiguous.

It's also more than very likely the program stores the data in RAM in a different format than what it would write to disk.  So you would need to be intimately familiar with how that program is using that data in RAM.